# What font is used on Geographic Information Systems.SE?

Tags: font-identification, logo

What's the font name used in the [Geographic Information Systems.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) logo?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the CSS for the page reveals it to be Museo Slab 500. This is a **free** font from exljbris. http://www.exljbris.com/museoslab.html

[image: Exljbris Museo Slab]

Answer (score 9):

[**Museo Slab**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo-slab/). The same typeface is used as a web font on the site for titles, inspecting the styling applied to those elements will reveal which font is used:

[image: Chrome Web Tools]